# dojo: widget already registered error

Tags: dojo, widget, destroy

I know this seems like a common error and I have tried to implement some jquery or Dojo code to fix the problem but nothing has helped so far--I keep getting the same error: Widget Already Registered with ID...

Here is my code:

```
$( "div" ).remove( "#div_temperature_legend" ); //jquery        
dojo.create("div", { id: "div_temperature_legend", innerHTML: "<p></p>" }, "legendPanel"); 
var legend = new esri.dijit.Legend({
              map: map,
              layerInfos: [{ layer: layer, title: "Temperature" }],
    }, "div_temperature_legend");
legend.startup();
```

the above code is in a button click function and that function is itself part of a large dojo `require()` function; and works the first time. The jQuery line does seem to remove because the legends don't get duplicated in the newly created `div_temperature_legend` layer.

Anyway, I have tried dojo's `destroy()` function but I still get the same error. I guess somehow, somewhere I need to `register` this div and then destroy it. But how? where? In the context of my code?

**Ideally, code should detect the widget if it exists and doesn't create another legend.**

Thanks.

Comment: the jquery code removes the `div`, but the reference of the widget (i.e esri.dijit.Legent is still available in the registry. To destroy the widget, which removes the reference in the registry you need to do something like this. `legend.destroy()` before creating a `new esri.dijit.Legend`.

Answer (score 1):

The error resides in the wrong disposal of dojo widget. Once it created, it will be set in registry hash by its ID. You could either 
a) dispose the widget dojo way
or
b) create unique ID for the widget each time.

In case you have multiple widgets of same kind the use of ID is not a good idea. better to skip the ID and use the class attribute instead. ID will be auto-assigned but you have no interest in it as selector could use the class name you assigned.

Comment: Okay, so how to use the class attributes? And won't the widget keep getting the legends content unless I somehow remove it? Like I am doing using jquery right now? Thanks

Comment: $('.myWidgetType').forEach( function(el){ dijit.byNode(el).destroy(); }

Comment: //1. destroy all instances of your widget

    $('.esriLegend').forEach( function(el){ dijit.byNode(el).destroy(); }

// 2. create a new one same way as you did but with className instead of id.

    var node = dojo.create("div", { class: "esriLegend", innerHTML: "<p></p>" }, "legendPanel");

    new esri.dijit.Legend({...},node).startup();

The templated widget is a bit simpler to use though.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I implemented my solution based on @Sasha idea of unique Div IDs:

```
$("#"+div_legend_global).remove();
div_legend_global = "div_" + new Date().getTime().toString();//div_legend_global defined globally
dojo.create("div", { id: div_legend_global, innerHTML: "<p></p>"    }, "legendPanel"); 
var legend = new esri.dijit.Legend({
              map: map,
              layerInfos: [{ layer: layer, title: "Temperature" }],
         }, div_legend_global);
legend.startup();
```

So I defined a global variable called `div_legend_global` and then, within the button click function, assign it unique value. That unique value then becomes the ID of the create Legend() function. After subsequent calls, jquery removes the unique div, thus preventing multiple instances of the legends in display.

Now, Dojo may be keeping in its stack the div and I think it would have been better to remove from the stack. But I am okay for now.

Thanks @Sasha.

Comment: I think this will create memory leaks in your code. Even though the domNode is destroyed the dojo object still resides in the memory. An alternative approach would be to use the `dijit.registry( 'widget_id').destroy()` and then recreate the legend widget.

Comment: Okay, but where and how do I add the div to the Registry--I think I had suspected I would be needing to do something like that but couldn't figure out. I did try domConsrtruct.destroy() but didnt' help. Thanks

Comment: Meengla you don't need to register the widget if you're creating it. It should already be registered. Another alternative you can look into if you absolutely need IDs, is to use the registry's getUniqueId function to give you a unique ID each time which you can store in some variable of your choosing. See https://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_registry_getUniqueId for more info on getUniqueId and all other registry methods.

Comment: frank's comment should also be an answer. ;)  This is a classic case of [mixing up DOM and Dijit APIs](http://kennethfranqueiro.com/2010/06/of-dijits-and-dom-nodes/) (that blog post is old but the destruction part of it still applies 5 years later).  DOM destroy APIs know nothing of Dijit widgets.

Comment: Sorry, but none of the suggestions have worked: I tried Frank's but still get the same error--apparently destroy is not working. I am able to detect by using 'var node_legend = dom.byId("div_legend")' and then tried Frank's as well as 'domConstruct.destroy("div_legend");' but no effect--the same error. I am moving on. Will leave this for later. Thanks all.